# setting background from ressources :Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android

I am new in development Android apps, I'm trying to set the background directly from resources and I keep getting this Exception.

> MainActivity.java

```
package imed.aouidene.com.wallpaper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  Button next;
  int count;
  int tab[] = new int[3];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    count = 0 ;
    String s = "" ;

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        s="drawable/image"+(i+1)+".jpg";
        tab[i]=getResources().getIdentifier(s,"drawable",getPackageName());
    }

    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(tab[count]);


    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (count < 2) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }
            getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(tab[count]);
        }
    });
}
}
```

the problem is at:
    ***getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(tab[count]);***

Comment: I've never used that `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource` like that, I normally use it on `PopupDialog`'s `Window`.. But I recommend you to get reference of the main layout of your layout or anything really which you can use as a background and do `setBackground` there.. And what exception do you get? I am answering blindly here lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change s like this:

```
s = "image"+(i+1);
```

just get the resource name!